# invalid conversion from int* to int [-fpermissive]

Tags: c++, arrays, bubble-sort

I am trying to sort a multidimensional array with bubblesort. When i try to commit the array to my bubblesort function i get several errors:

```
   bubblesort(lottozahlen[12] [6], k);
void bubblesort(int *array [12] [6], int length)
{
    int i, j, k;
    for (k=0; k&lt;12; k++)
    {

        for (i = 0; i &lt; length -1; ++i)
        {

            for (j = 0; j &lt; length - i - 1; ++j)
            {
                if (array [k] [j] &gt; array [k] [j + 1])
                {
                    int tmp = array[k] [j];
                    array[k] [j] = array[k] [j + 1];
                    array [k] [j + 1] = tmp;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The errors are :

```
[Error] invalid conversion from 'int*' to 'int' [-fpermissive] 
[Error] invalid conversion from 'int' to 'int*' [-fpermissive] 
[Error] invalid conversion from 'int' to 'int* (*)[6]' [-fpermissive] 
[Error]   initializing argument 1 of 'void bubblesort(int* (*)[6], int)' [-fpermissive]
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `lottozahlen` is declared as `int lottozahlen[12][6]`:

```
void bubblesort(int *array [12] [6], int length)
```

here the `array` parameter is declared as an array of array of pointers. Not what you want.

```
bubblesort(lottozahlen[12] [6], k);
```

here you call `bubblesort` with the element of the array at position `(12, 6)` as the first argument. Not want you want either.

It should be:

```
bubblesort(lottozahlen, k);
void bubblesort(int array [12] [6], int length)
```